# How to get and trim contents of jspwriter (out) buffer

Tags: java, jsp, buffer, trim, bufferedwriter

On a `JSP` page, the `JSPService` exposes the `JSPWriter class` in the form of `out` as in `out.println("foobar");` What I'd like to do is store the contents of the `out buffer` to a String variable and then `trim` said variable. The problem is I'm not quite sure to capture the contents of the out buffer.

I was trying to figure out a way to trim the buffer directly, but I cannot find such a way. So, I thought maybe what might work is output the contents of the buffer to a String variable, trim the variable itself, clear the out buffer, and then write the variable to the out buffer:

```
// Returns the object, not the contents of the buffer
// Need the contents for the rest of the code to work
String outBufferContents = out.toString();

// Trim out buffer contents
outBufferContents = outBufferContents.trim();

// Clear out buffer
out.clearBuffer();

// Write trimmed buffer contents to out buffer
out.print(outBufferContents);
```

Do you have any suggestions on how I may grab the contents of the out buffer or even trim the out buffer directly?

Thank you very much for any help you may provide.

Comment: Why can't you trim the String before you put it into the buffer? If you can't do that then you could try a Filter on the response.

Comment: It's a good question. Because the response is being written to a separate web server, which is outside of my control, and I'd prefer to trim the contents before the out buffer is flushed and sent off than have the web server which initiated the request perform string manipulation. The code above is on a web server I control. I trust a filter on the response would work. Thank you for that.